# Why do I get $0$ in the following integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

The solution to the following integral should be $-2$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}  \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)}\,\mathrm{d}v = -2.
$$
However, I obtain $0$ (this looks to me just like the Gaussian integral.
$$
\left[\lim_{t \to-\infty} \int_{t}^0 - \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}dv + \lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{0}^{t} - \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}dv\right] = 0
$$
What am I doing wrong?

## Following Comments

Since it is an even function we have
$$
\begin{align}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}  \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)}dv 
&= 2\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}  \frac{|v|}{(1 - u^2)}dv  \\
&= 2\left[\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2(1 - u^2)}\right\}\right]_0^{\infty} \\
&= 2\left[0 - 1\right] = -2.
\end{align}
$$
How does one solve it without using the fact that the integrand is an even function?

Comment: The two integral terms add up, they do not vanish

Comment: If $u^2\ge0,u^2<1$ (In other case the improper integral under consideration diverges.), then the command of Mathematica `Integrate[Exp[-v^2/2/(1 - u^2)]*v, {v, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> u^2 >= 0 && u^2 < 1]` performs $1-u^2$.

Comment: $u$ is a variable in the integrand but shouldn't affect these calculations. Essentially $u\in [-1, 1]$, I think

Comment: @DIdier_ how come? I swear you get $[1 - 0] + [0 - 1]$ which vanishes?

Comment: So that I would be able to get an exact derivative

Comment: @Euler_Salter The integrand is an even function, the two integrals take the same value.

Comment: @DIdier_ do you mind writing an answer for that? I just want to see how you go about it

Comment: Oh wait, we have $|v|$ not $v$!

Comment: The two integrals together are $-2$ but what about the factor with pi and the square root?

Comment: @vitamind oh sorry I made a typo there

Comment: @DIdier_ how does one prove this without using the fact that the integrated is even?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Is your question how to solve the integral without splitting it up?

Comment: @vitamind No splitting it up is fine! I just wanted to solve the integral by splitting it first into an integral between $(-\infty, 0)$ and one between $(0, \infty)$ as one would usually do. But I get $0$ in that case, rather than $-2$

Comment: @Euler_Salter I'm sorry if that's a stupid comment but did you understand it now or should someone write an anwer?

Comment: @vitamind I understand it fine when using the fact that the integrated is even. However I would like to solve the integral without using that fact.

Comment: So you want to prove it by using $\lim_{t\to\infty}$, =splitting the integral up?

Comment: @vitamind exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplification purposes we will define $\tau=1-u^2$. We want to show that
$$\left[-\lim_{t \to-\infty} \int\limits_{t}^0  \frac{|v|}{\tau}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2\tau}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}v - \lim_{t\to\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{t}  \frac{|v|}{\tau}\exp\left\{-\frac{v^2}{2\tau}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}v\right] = -2.
$$
For the first integral substitute $v=-\nu.$ This yields
$$\lim_{t \to-\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{-t}  \frac{|-\nu|}{\tau}\exp\left\{-\frac{(-\nu)^2}{2\tau}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\nu= \lim_{t \to\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{t}  \frac{\nu}{\tau}\exp\left\{-\frac{\nu^2}{2\tau}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\nu.$$
Now $\nu$ is running over non-negative values only. That means we can omit the absolut value. Furthermore this integral is equivalent to our second integral. If we call them both $I$ our final solution will be $-I-I$.

Substitute $\mu=-\frac{\nu^2}{2\tau}.$ The differential is going to be $d\nu=-\frac{\tau}{\nu}d\mu.$ That leaves us with
$$I=-\lim_{t \to\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{-\frac{t^2}{2\tau}}  \exp\left\{\mu\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\mu=-\left[\lim_{t \to\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\tau}}-e^0\right]=1.$$
We know $I=1$. Our solution is $-I-I$, so it's your desired $-2$.